# Codeigniter custom output array from query

Tags: database, arrays, codeigniter, loops, model

I have a function in my model for selecting items from a database and returning it as an array.  My question is, how can I manually create the array, so that I can for example, change the date format?

Here is what I have:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM prayer_requests ORDER BY id DESC';
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);

        if($query->num_rows() > 0) return $query->result();
        else return FALSE;
```

I'm guessing I would need some kind of loop?  I know it must be simple, but can't figure out exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the result as an array, you can use `result_array()` instead of `result()`.
You can read more about generating results with CodeIgniter here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

Ex:

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");
$rows = $query->result_array(); // $rows is now an array containing all the rows from the query result
```

**EDIT**:
If you want to modify the data before putting it into the array. You'll need a loop, and while in the loop, use any functions necessary to change the data you want. Then assign it back the loop variable, and append it to an array (which has already been initialized before the loop).

```
$rows = array();
foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
{
    $row['some_key'] = change_data($row['some_key');
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: I realize that, but how do I modify the data before it gets put into the array?

Comment: Looks good, but having some trouble.  Am I doing something wrong here? foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
  {
      $row['date'] = standard_date("DATE_ISO8601", $row['date');
      $rows[] = $row;
  }
  return $rows;

Comment: @Adam your code looks fine to me. But can you explain what's the trouble? Is it not returning anything? Or perhaps there's an error message? Also, what's the original content of `$row['date']`? Remember, the second parameter of `standard_date()` must be a Unix timestamp.

Comment: I'm just getting a blank white screen, which means something is broken.  I replaced the date format with this: $row['content'] = "hey"; and i'm still getting a blank screen :/

Comment: Fixed!! I had to replace $row['date'] with $row->date.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

First things first: your model will return the result, the controller will do the job, for example:

```
//Picking data
$this->data['resultados']           = $this->outros_detalhes_model->consulta();
$rows = array();

//Running all data, modifying whatever you need
foreach($this->data['resultados'] as $row){
   $row->CT_TIPO = $this->funcoes->mostra_tipo_detalhe($row->CT_TIPO);
   $rows[] = $row;
}

//Sending data to view
$this->data['resultados'] = $rows;
$this->load->view('includes/estrutura',$this->data);
```